Azure Pipeline not able to list all git remotes
We have a gradle script where a git command is executed (git branch --remotes). Unfortunately when running this in new pipelines all that is returned is the current branch looking like origin/3a64b9307802044f4ab6c1332832d6067906d309. I think it is the head of that branch. Anyways, it's only one branch, when multiple branches should be there and it is not readable.
We have old pipelines in which it runs just fine.
Same is also visible in the Checkout-phase of the azure pipeline, after resolving all deltas and the branches are listed. In old pipelines all branches are listed in human readable format while in the new pipeline only one branch is listed. It somehow does not affect tags, as they are all listed in both pipelines.
I already checked permissions of both (old, new) pipelines and they are equal and in fact everything seems equal.
Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem?

Have you checked Fetch Depth in the Pipeline Configuration?

please accept that I answered your question below thanks.

Hi @Jimedem, since Derek's suggestion to disable shallow fetch works for you, would you consider the issue in this post as resolved by his answer? Thx for your sharing to benefit other community members. And thank you Derek for the efforts and insights.

Not sure if it's a good idea to set fetchDepth: 0 in the checkout task. Try something like git branch --all | grep origin instead of git branch --remotes. See git branch documentation for more details.

Check the Fetch Depth in the Pipeline Configuration. here is an addition you can add to the pipeline yaml file.
steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0


You can customize your checkout step to disable the default shallow fetch configured with a depth of 1
steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0 # Disable default shallow fetch
- script: |
    git branch --remotes



Setting fetchDepth: 0 in the checkout task means that the full history of the branch will be fetched, which might take a while depending on the branch.
Try the following instead:
git branch --all --format='%(refname)' | grep refs/remotes/origin/

Example output:

